# Issues with Curve Modifier

Tags: modeling

Been working on this tutorial and have tried another similar one using the curve modifier, and have experienced the same issues. I don't seem to have any issues with the curve modifier to shape the tread with the wheel shape from the base.

In the tut an array modifier along with another curve mod and empty is used to wrap around a Bezier circle to achieve the tyre.[image]

When this is tried I get very wacky results.

Would appreciate if someone could help me with a workaround for this issue. The link for tut is below.

Tutorial Link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcIu2hIO4Og&t=1398s&ab_channel=CGMasters

Comment: In the tutorial, the  curve-circle  is used only to measure the number of tread-sections it takes to fill the circumference, for the array. The deformation around the wheel is actually done with an Empty to set the direction, and _Simple Deform > Bend_ . (Just checking you've got that, before going into more detail)

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @RobinBetts Hi Robin, Many thanks for looking into this for me. Yes, I understand the details with the empty and deform modifiers. But don't understand why the array is set to Z when it puts the array in the incorrect position going up.